# Does Clang have an equivalent to GNU GCC's preprocessor assert directive?

Tags: c++, g++, clang, preprocessor

With GNU/GCC there is exists a preprocessor assertion directive feature that takes the form:

```
#predicate (answer)
```

See [GCC Assertions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/cpp/Assertions.html#:%7E:text=Assertions%20are%20made%20with%20the,that%20identifies%20assertions%20in%20conditionals.&text=You%20may%20make%20several%20assertions,ones%20for%20the%20same%20predicate.).

Does the Clang compiler/preprocessor have an equivalent feature?

Comment: Just test it with clang compiler. You have linked documentation of very old gcc. Clang was started to be as much compatible with gcc as possible, so it should work.

Comment: [doesn't look like it](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

Comment: Why do you need this? Even the GCC alternative linked says it's best not to use it at all. If you tell us why you need it we may be able to come up with some other helpful way to solve your problem.

Comment: What's wrong with `#if` -> `#error` or a `static_assert`?

Answer (score 0):

> Does the Clang compiler/preprocessor have an equivalent feature?

No. Use predefined macros specific to the environment, like `__linux__` or `__X86_64__` etc.